# How to write extension function with nested generics?

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have extension function on Single class:

```
fun <T: Response<BaseResponse>> Single<T>.checkResponse(): Single<BaseResponse> {
    return this.map { some code }
}
```

And trying to use it like:

```
fun sign(body: Map<String, String>): Single<SignResponse> {
    return service.sign(body).checkResponse().map { it }
}
```

Service's sign signature:

```
@POST(Urls.SIGN)
fun sign(@Body body: Map<String, String>): Single<Response<SignResponse>>
```

SignResponse inherits BaseResponse obviously

Response is retrofit2.response

And I've got an error:

> `Type parameter bound for T in fun <T : Response<BaseResponse>> Single<T>.checkResponse(): Single<BaseResponse> is not satisfied: inferred type Response<SignResponse> is not a subtype of Response<BaseResponse>`

How do I need to write extension function to tell compiler that Single have Response, which have type inherited from BaseResponse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
fun <R: BaseResponse, T: Response<R>> Single<T>.checkResponse(): Single<R>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I tried something similar, but apparently i made a mistake somewhere.